# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, IPv4Address found when iterating through a for loop

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to portscan an ip range. So far, I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import ipaddress
import sys


def portscan(host):
    try:
        for port in range(1,445):  
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
            if result == 0: #the error indictator returns 0 if the operation succeeds.
                print "port",port," is open on",host
            # else:
            #     print "port ",port," is closed"     
            sock.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print " CTRL+C Interruption. Exiting..." 
        sys.exit() 


def main():
    subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(u'192.168.0.0/29')
    test = '192.168.0.1'
    for i in subnet:
        print i
        portscan(i)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The issue this gives is the following:

```
    result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, IPv4Address found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I can pass the `portscan` function the variable `test` with `portscan(test)` containing 192.168.0.1 and I can directly pass `portscan` the ip: `portscan('192.168.0.1')` and both of these methods run the function and give the expected outcome.

But when I try to iterate through a range I get the `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, IPv4Address found` issue.

I'm not sure how to progress from here.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of host? Try `type(host)`

Comment: I'm new to this, but I got: `<type 'str'>`